# Ruby 1.9.2 syntax error

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, syntax-error, ruby-1.9.2

So I have code that runs just fine on ruby 1.8.7, but on 1.9.2 it doesn't work.

Here's the error message:

```
rake aborted!
/u/apps/proxy/releases/20111115125519/db/seeds.rb:16: syntax error, unexpected tASSOC, expecting ')'
  :image_url => 'dooropen',
           ^
/u/apps/proxy/releases/20111115125519/db/seeds.rb:16: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting $end
```

Here's the relevant part of the code:

```
door_on_state = BoxStateConfiguration.create (
  :image_url => 'dooropen',
  :color => '#CD493B',
  :label => 'Ytterdörr öppen',
  :interactive => false
)
```

I added `# encoding: utf-8` to the top of the file, since that's sometimes the problem when it runs on 1.8.7, but not 1.9.2, but that didn't change anything.

Does anyone know what ruby is complaining about?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried removing the space between `create` and `(`? If Ruby doesn't realize that you want to call a method, you can't leave off the `{}`, since that's reserved for handling a hash as last argument in a method.

```
>> def foo(h) ; end #=> nil
>> foo (:foo => "bar")
SyntaxError: (irb):2: syntax error, unexpected tASSOC, expecting ')'
foo (:foo => "bar")
            ^
(irb):2: syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting $end
    [snip]
>> foo(:foo => "bar") #=> nil
```

Comment: Tried removing the space... Didn't help. Tried adding {}... Didn't help. Tried both at the same time... Didn't help. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Strange that removing the space didn't work. See my update, adding the space causes exactly the error you describe, while removing it fixed it.

Comment: That must be a bug... White space shouldn't matter... I tried your example in irb and you're right, `foo(:foo => "bar")` works.

Comment: Wasn't there already a warning in 1.8 that there should be no space between a method name and the opening parenthesis of the argument list? b

Comment: I just checked with 1.8.7: `foo ()
(irb):2: warning: don't put space before argument parentheses`.

Comment: I tried removing the space again. All of them and this time it worked. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

@MichaelKohl's answer is exactly correct. You need to remove the space before the paren for the method call. Here's proof:

```
phrogz$ cat original.rb 
door_on_state = BoxStateConfiguration.create (
  :image_url => 'dooropen',
)

phrogz$ ruby -c original.rb
original.rb:2: syntax error, unexpected tASSOC, expecting ')'
  :image_url => 'dooropen',
               ^
original.rb:2: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting $end

phrogz$ cat fixed.rb 
door_on_state = BoxStateConfiguration.create(
  :image_url => 'dooropen',
)

phrogz$ ruby -cv fixed.rb 
ruby 1.9.2p180 (2011-02-18 revision 30909) [x86_64-darwin10.7.0]
Syntax OK
```

Comment: Confirmed. I must have done something wrong when I tested it the first time, but it works now, thanks!